# Matrix representation of a orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Hey can some help me with these kinds of questions have a lot of them and I can't figure out how to do them thanks

Let $v = (cos \theta, sin\theta)^{T} \in R^2$ for some angle $\theta \in 2^{R}$, and let $P_{v}$ denote the orthogonal projection corresponding to v. Find the matrix representation of $P_{v}$ with respect to the standard basis for $R^{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The orthogonal projection onto $v$ is defined by $w \mapsto \dfrac{\left<v,w\right>}{|v|^2}v  = \dfrac{1}{|v|^2}v\left(v^T w\right) = \left(\dfrac{1}{|v|^2}vv^T\right) w$

Comment: I know that but what is $w$ in this case?

Comment: $w$ is any other vector. We're trying to find the matrix $A$ so that $Aw$ is equal to 'the orthogonal projection of $w$ onto $v$'. I.e. it's not part of the definition of $A$, but rather it's used to demonstrate *what* $A$ does.

Comment: ohh okay so we could use the standard basis for $R^2$ which is (1,0) to find a projection and convert it to matrix form am I right?

Comment: The part about using the standard basis is sort of implicit in my use of the standard inner product to define the projection. Try writing out the matrix $\frac{1}{|v|^2}vv^T$ (can you see why this defines a matrix?) and see if that works for you.

Alternately (more along the lines of what I think you're thinking of), you can use the fact that the projection of $(1,0)$ onto $v$ will give you the first column of $A$, and the projection of $(0,1)$ onto $v$ will give you the second column. Try both of these methods and see if you get the same answer.

Comment: is the answer 1?

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{|v|^2}vv^T = \frac{1}{cos^2 \theta + sin^2 \theta}[cos \theta sin \theta][cos \theta sin \theta]^T =\frac{1}{1} \times [1] = [1]$

Comment: You have the vectors 'sideways'. $vv^T = \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\theta \\ \sin\theta \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos^2\theta & \sin\theta\cos\theta \\ \sin\theta\cos\theta & \sin^2\theta \end{array}\right)$